# Loop through form array based on user input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have select menu with options if user select 1 then i have to display one form or if user select 2 i have to display 2 same forms but here if i push 2 forms after that push 3 it displays 5 forms total. What i have tried till now

```
<select (change)="selectedvalue($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let num of number" [value]="num.num">{{num.num}}</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container">

    <form [formGroup]="myForm">

        <div formArrayName="addresses" >
            <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">

                <div [formGroupName]="i" class="myform">
                    <label>street</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street"><br><br>
                    <label>postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
                </div><br><br>
            </div>
        </div><br><br>
            <pre>form value: <br>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
    </form>

</div>
```

you can see full working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bd8bsq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add/Remove based on the number selected. The following code adds/removes `forms` from the end.

```
    if(e < control.length) {
      for (let i = control.length - 1; i >= e ; i--) {
        control.removeAt(i);
      }      
    } else {
      let moreRequired = e - control.length;
      for (let i = 1; i <= moreRequired ; i++) {
        control.push(this.initAddress());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code as:

```
selectedvalue(e) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
    this.clearFormArray(control);
    for (var i = 0; i < e; i++) {      
        control.push(this.initAddress());
    }
}

clearFormArray = (formArray: FormArray) => {
    while (formArray.length !== 0) {
        formArray.removeAt(0)
    }
}
```

> you will have to clear `FormArray` before pushing elements in it.

Comment: By clearing the FormArray, he'll loose the already filled data in the form.

Comment: Sorry i can not accept 2 answers. That means this code is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how many forms are still there and then append rest number of forms.

```
  selectedvalue(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < e; i++) {
      const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];      
      control.push(this.initAddress());
    }
  }
```

in the above method you're just adding the more 2 forms instead of adding just 1 as you already have 1.

```
selectedvalue(e) {
        let existingLen = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];
        for (var i = 0; i < (e - existingLen.length); i++) {
          const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['addresses'];      
          control.push(this.initAddress());
        }
}
```

This should be your method.

Note : With this method you'll need to handle the decrease of number of forms too.

Comment: It'll not work when you decrease the number from dropdown.

Comment: Well that's true, you need to handle that either.

Comment: also there could be one optimization in above code as `for (var i = existingLen.length; i < e; i++) `

Comment: Yes it is not working if i decrease the number @AnshumanJaiswal

Comment: @Urock, you probably wanna ask user remove them one by one, because removing it could cause data loss, suppose if someone has filled the form and then decrease it he'll loose that data, that's part of UX that you need to handle.

Comment: Actually the problem is First user select how many addresses he want if he selects 2 from select menu i have to display 2 forms but here user can not change at this moment if he want to change he must go back and change select option based on that option i have to display number of forms.